# Cloud Foundry quantum state - organization simultaneously exists and fails to exist

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I have a barebones Cloud Foundry instance running on BOSH-Lite, and I am running into an absolutely puzzling situation. Cloud Foundry claims that I have no org. When I try to create the org, Cloud Foundry claims the org already exists. When I try to target the org, Cloud Foundry claims the org doesn't exist. What is Cloud Foundry doing?

```
$ cf orgs
Getting orgs as karan...
No orgs found.

$ cf create-org orgname
Creating org orgname as karan...
OK
Org orgname already exists

$ cf target -o orgname
Organization 'orgname' not found.
FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is an org in the Cloud Controller database named `orgname` that you do not have access to. For security reasons, if you do not have access to an org, it is exactly the same as it not existing, from your point of view.